# How to change TimedRotatingFileHandler to mode 'w' in logging.conf file

Tags: python, logging

I have a `logging.conf` file, with the following content:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=file

[formatters]
keys=simple

[formatter_simple]
format=[%(levelname)s] %(asctime)s : %(name)s - %(message)s
datefmt=%H:%M:%s

[handlers]
keys=file

[handler_file]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
interval=midnight
backupCount=5
formatter=simple
level=INFO
args=(log_directory,)
```

I want to delete the older logs everytime I run the code, therefore I would like to set `mode` to `w` however I am not sure how to do it.

```
[handler_file]
...
kwargs={'mode': 'w'}
```

doesn't seem to work (the logger is still appending logs instead of overwriting the existing log file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mode` is not a valid argument for [`TimeRotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler):

```
class logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename, when='h', interval=1, backupCount=0, encoding=None, delay=False, utc=False)
```

and therefore, it defaults to appending logs to existing log file(s). You can use [`RotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) instead and set `mode` to `w` in `args`:

```
[handler_file]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
...
args=(log_directory,'w')
```

Comment: In my experience, RotatingFileHandler also seems to ignore the 'w' mode and always appends. This also seems to be indicated by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52229274/logs-dont-overwrite)

Comment: From looking at [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/logging/handlers.py) (lines 146-152), this is indeed the case, by design. This means if I have a lot of output such that a single log file would be too big, but am only interested in the last run, I have to handle deleting old log files myself.

Answer (score 2):

At this time, filemode `'a'` is hard-coded for `logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler`:

```py
BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, filename, 'a', encoding=encoding,
                             delay=delay, errors=errors)
```

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L207

Comment: The reason is that's the most useful value. No point in submitting a bug report - it's not a bug, it's working as designed.

Comment: No offence taken, but 'w' doesn't make sense if you want log files that capture activity over specific periods of time. You don't want to lose previous results from a time-slot, which could happen with 'w'. Also I didn't want to add too much to the signature of `TimedRotatingFileHandler`.